# pl/sql oracle print out employee duration in years, months, days

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this function defined:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION oz_hire_duration(hiredate IN DATE)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS workexperience VARCHAR2(30);

BEGIN
    workexperience := TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hiredate)/12) || 'years ' ||
    MOD(TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hiredate)), 12) || ' month '||
    TRUNC(SYSDATE - ADD_MONTHS(hiredate, TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hiredate)))) || 'days';

RETURN workexperience;
END;
```

I don't know why it always give me errors, could anyone please help?

This is the error message I get when I compile this function:

> ORA-06575: Package or function OZ_HIRE_DURATION is in an invalid state
>
> Errors: FUNCTION OZ_HIRE_DURATION Line/Col: 8/21 PLS-00103:
> Encountered the symbol "-" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ```
> . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>
> <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or default
> like like2 like4 likec as between from using || multiset
> member submultiset The symbol ". was inserted before "-" to continue.
> ```

Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxdma.png)

Comment: "Duration in years, months, days" is not well defined. For example: from 28 February 2019 to 29 February 2020 - is that a year and a day, or exactly a year? You must specify a very clear, un-ambiguous definition for all such exceptional cases. Except that, unfortunately, there is **no** such set of rules that, simultaneously, covers all possible cases **and** does not contradict itself. So... good luck with this task!

Comment: It compiles and runs fine for me ([DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c1023a735aa4132853cf19fdbef5af6a)).

Answer (score 0):

just put following select statement instead of your calculation.

my idea is calculating years, months and days sequentially.

```
SELECT vyears || ' years ' || vmonth || ' months ' || FLOOR(SYSDATE - add_months(hiredate, (vyears * 12) + vmonth)) || ' days' AS workexperience
INTO WorkExperience
FROM (SELECT SYSDATE,
                         vyears,
                         FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hiredate)) - (vyears * 12) vmonth
                FROM (SELECT SYSDATE,
                                         FLOOR(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, hiredate) / 12) vyears
                                FROM dual));
```